# Complex roots and singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, branch-points

Maybe the question is trivial, but I cannot find an answer according to the standard books of Complex Analysis.
We have three kinds of singularities: isolated, pole, and essential.

What kind of singularities are the following ones?

> 1) $\frac{1}{\sqrt z} \text{ in } z=0$
>
> 2) $\frac{1}{\sqrt z-1} \text{ in } z=1$

One could make up a "fractionary order" pole, but they are not provided in usual terminology, since the Laurent series is on integer numbers... The problem is that they actually do not admit any Laurent expansion in the foregoing points, and thus one cannot say that they are essential singularities and apply the Picard theorem....

So what's the truth?

Comment: Those functions do not have isolated singularities but rather algebraic branch points.  Removable singularity, pole, and essential singularity are all isolated singularities.

Comment: I tried to edit in mathjax. Did you mean $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}-1}$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z-1}}$ in (2)?

Comment: In order to make (1) into a single-valued function in the first place, you'll first have to specify some branch cut.  Once you do that, the singularity becomes essential.

Comment: @DanielSchepler your answer seems to contradict the one of sharding4. What the question is looking for is a proof, if they actually are isolated singularity, how can we prove that? Usual definition with $|f(z)|$ or the negative coefficients of Laurent series do not work here...

Comment: I guess it depends on the exact definition of "essential singularity" - to me it doesn't necessarily imply isolated, just that it fails to be either a removable singularity or a pole singularity.

Comment: @sharding4, let us suppose that we of course choose to cut the branch along the semi-straight line Rez<0, Imz=0. Cleary z=1 does not belong to this cut, but still it is an isolated singularity, since the function is analytical in every punctured neighbourhood of the indicated point. This certainly applies at case 2). For case 1), z=0 represents definitely a non-isolated singularity, since it belongs to the branch, so your answer fullfills correctly the first case, I guess.

Comment: But I guess if you use Wikipedia's definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity then that requires $f$ to be holomorphic on some punctured neighborhood of $a$ for the definition even to apply, and that's impossible to satisfy for any branch cut of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$.  (My reading of that definition is that asking the question what type of singularity it is doesn't even make sense then.)

Comment: @BoySimone  From Wikipedia "a complex number $z_0$ is an isolated singularity of a function $f$ if there exists an open disk $D$ centered at $z_0$ such that $f$ is holomorphic on $D \setminus \{z_0\}$"

Comment: @DanielSchepler that was what I thought too, but all of the textbook on Complex Analysis I know present the Laurent series as a check for the essential singularity, and they classify isolated singularities in poles, removable and essentials one. But I do not understand how to apply this for case 2). The point is  that Picard theorem says that in any neighbourhood of an essential singularity, the function reaches any complex value save for one at most, which is not true for this case 2).

Comment: Of course, in (2), if you branch cut along the negative real axis for example, then $z=1$ is a simple pole because $(z-1) f(z) = \sqrt{z} + 1$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of 1.

Comment: Ok, so the answer seems that 1) is not a isolated singularity, whereas 2) is a simple pole. Thanks guys!

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  Sorry about my confusion.  I thought you had $1/\sqrt{z-1}$ for 2)